# Can "I could hand in the report yesterday" mean the completion of the action?

Tags: usage

In most Grammar book says that (a) is not correct and you should use (b) or (c) if you want to say that you completed the action.

a. I could hand in the report yesterday.
b. I was able to hand in the report yesterday.
c. I handed in the report yesterday.

However, a few native English speakers say that (a) is also okay and means the same as (c).
Another native speaker says that (a) and (b) have the same meaning, showing the possibility. Whether the speaker accomplished the action or not is ambiguous.
Many Japanese students use (a) when they want to say that they accomplished the action being influenced by the Japanese Dekita, which is used as a polite expression rather than having the ability to do something.

What would you think?

Comment: (a) does not make sense. "I could..." expresses current ability or future possibility, which does not work with "yesterday". Whomever you're talking to about English, stop doing it. They are clearly misinforming you.

Comment: I could dance when I was 20; I find it hard now.

Comment: I could drive yesterday; I can't today because my licence (BrE spelling) has been suspended.

Comment: "Could" never means "successfully did" about a single past event. In the past, it describes having an ability, so sentence a) means something like, "Yesterday I knew how to hand in the report", implying that today I don't know how. Sentence b) has the meaning you intend, and c) is good grammar, but lacks the nuance of success.